# Mapstruct map a property for a null object

Tags: java, dictionary, mapstruct

I have a particular problem to generate the map implementation, I need to map a property of a null object. The code is like this in `ObjectRequestMapper`:

```
    @Mapper(collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED, nullValueCheckStrategy =
           NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS, nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_NULL, uses = {
           WrapperGrpcMapper.class, AddressRequestMapper.class })
    public interface ObjectRequestGrpcMapper {

      @Mapping(target = "wcsStoreId", source = "storeId")
      @Mapping(target = "linesList", source = "lines")
      ObjectRequest map(Long storeId, @Context String countryCode, List<ObjectLines> lines, Address address);

      ObjectRequestLine lineToProto (ObjectLine line);

    }
```

and the `AddressRequestMapper`:

```
    public interface AddressRequestMapper {

      default Address toProto(Address address, @Context String countryCode){
          return this.map(address, countryCode);
      }

      Address map(Address address, String countryCode);
    }
```

When I call the map of `ObjectRequest` passing all parameters with `countryCode = "EN"` and object address is null, the mapper of `AddresRequestMapper` doesn't applies because `ObjectRequestMapper` checks the `Address == null`, and then doesn't map `ObjectRequest.Address` to address

It is possible to get a solution for this case?

Thanks

Comment: The solution that I implemented is using a @Aftermapping check the address is null, set the countryCode

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get instead of "Address == null" -> "new Address()" just do change:

`nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT`